# PreProcessing in Python - Classification Exercise

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Is there anything prescriptive about which kind of preprocessing technique to use?

For now, I am trying to perform a classification where the dataset comprises of categorical as well as numerical variables.

My question is whether there is any recommendation as to when to use MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler, and Normalizer.

Comment: As far as i know,people use Scalers like RobustScaler,MinMaxScaler,StandardScaler to normaize data so that each columns data is in range like -1 <= val <= 1,-0.1 <= val <= 0.1,3 <= val <=3. Doing pre-processing lets gradient descent algorithm to finish fast. All columns value should be of almost same scale otherwise it might create problem if 1 columns data varies from -10 to 10 and another columns data from -10000000 to 1000000. so we need to bring all to same scale to finish learning process fast.

Comment: See i got to know about scaling from this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gV5fD8Xbwgk

Answer (score 0):

There is no definite answer to this.

My recommendation is to apply the algorithm ones without preprocessing and check the classification report and the confusion matrix. Then apply it with preprocessing method and see the report and matrix again.

Preprocessing the data does not necessarily increase the accuracy of your algorithm.

Kindly check page 15 of the following paper, it shows that actually, some algorithm can take care of the processing within them.

http://wen.ijs.si/ojs-2.4.3/index.php/informatica/article/download/148/140